# Inconsistent behavior of bash string replacement

Tags: bash, filenames, variable

When I print a variable with one substring replacing another as described in [this documentation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), it behaves correctly:

```
stringZ='abc - 123'

echo $stringZ             # abc - 123

echo ${stringZ/ - /test}  # abctest123
```

However, if I get the string from a filename, the replacement is ignored completely:

```
for f in mp3/*; do

    stringZ=$(basename $f)

    echo $stringZ             # abc - 123.txt

    echo ${stringZ/ - /test}  # abc - 123.txt

done
```

How can I replace a substring in a variable derived from a filename?

Comment: Perhaps the dash you see is not the dash you wrote?

Comment: try `echo ... | hexdump -C` or `mp3/*' - '*` to see if file matches pattern at all

Comment: You should be getting some error messages there. Aren't you?

Comment: I'm not seeing any error messages. Is there way to make it more verbose?

Comment: `echo 'abc - 123.txt' | hexdump -C` and `echo $stringZ | hexdump -C` both output `00000000  61 62 63 20 2d 20 31 32  33 2e 74 78 74 0a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is, as usual, that [you need to always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#131767):

```
$ ls -N mp3/
abc - 123.txt
```

Now, let's try your loop:

```
$ for f in mp3/*; do 
    stringZ=$(basename $f); 
    echo $stringZ; 
    echo ${stringZ/ - /test} ; 
done
basename: extra operand ‘123.txt’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

What happens is that the `$f` variable has the value `mp3/abc - 123.txt`, so you are running `basename mp3/abc - 123.txt` and that complains since it sees the space and assumes that `mp3/abc` is the first argument. It should work as expected if you quote:

```
$ for f in mp3/*; do 
    stringZ=$(basename "$f"); 
    echo "$stringZ"; 
    echo "${stringZ/ - /test}" ; 
done
abc - 123.txt
abctest123.txt
```

Only the quotes in the `basename "$f"` are absolutely necessary here, but always quoting your variables is a good habit to get into.

Comment: Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary

Comment: good catch! I subconsciously quoted it when testing earlier. haha. (it could also be a typo in the question, as it had the echo and claimed the output was correct)

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day!